# adding another string in autocomplete edit text in android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

Hello guys i successfully created an auto-complete edit text, but i want to extend / add another string to the existing word. any ideas on how to do that.

Like after selecting a word from the dropdown menu, I should be able to add another word after typing a space or a comma.

Comment: use custom adapter for your `AutoCompleteTextView` and set `onItemClickListener` for the `AutoCompleteTextView` and in `onItemClick` append the string and setText() for the `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: To add multiple words after comma you should use multiautocompletetextview, use custom adapter to add items into the list. If you want to make it like bubble using ImageSpan with SpannableStringBuilder

Comment: Yes i implemented the onItemClickListener, now what methods should i override in the SimpleAdapter extended class (getView() or setTextView()), a brief tutorial would be helpfull.

Comment: i guess i have to extend from AutoCompleteTextView and implement methods...I just need to know the correct method which controls the drop down suggestions behaviour once i press any key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Muhammed Babar for your suggestion, and here is my answer for my question..

```
Sms = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    quickM = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quickmessages);

    //SMS message view autocomplete.........
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMessage = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, quickM);

    Sms.setAdapter(adapterMessage);
  //Set Tokenizer for SMS editText MultiAutoTextView
    Sms.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public int findTokenStart(CharSequence arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    });

  //Setting Sms edittext onclick listener class
    Sms.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            String name =  (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);


            if(Sms.getText().toString().length()==0)
                Sms.setText(name);
                else
                Sms.setText(Sms.getText().toString()+","+name);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Now the only problem i am facing is moving my cursor to the end of the  message box..?

Comment: Hello friend, I have implemented method to set cursor at the end of text, but after that input from end does not show suggested text. It only shows suggestions from beginning.